# Quantitative Risk Assessment Of Onshore Crude Oil Pipelines

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, pipelines, safety

I am currently working on a project that requires a quantitative risk assessment of a potential release (analysis of frequency and consequences) onshore pipelines transporting crude oil (underground). I have been reviewing several research papers and noticed that many of them use databases of historical accidents for their assessments.

Provided the pipeline system requires relevant information regarding the pipeline design and installation, properties of the fluid being transported, and the main conditions in the surroundings

While I understand the value of this approach, I have some concerns about its applicability to my study. Specifically, I am unsure how accidents involving pipelines with different pipeline systems are relevant to the parameters I will choose for my study.

I am unsure how to draw conclusions from this historical data given these differences.Could you provide some guidance on how I might approach this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The significant risks for the underground onshore pipeline would be corrosion, unofficial digging of locals and earthquakes.

1. Corrosion is a day-to-day activity needed to get the data through intelligent pigs, even though you have an anti-corrosion tech in place.
2. unofficial digging can occur anytime; the constant periodic monitoring of the site is the only option.
3. Earthquake data needs to be checked before laying the pipeline, and you can't predict an earthquake; only history matching is the best way to have an idea.

Coming to the practicality of the study, I suggest you visit a local pipeline company to get an idea about your study.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, a risk assessment should be data driven (evidence based) - so the question is where do you get your data from and how it is relevant?

The oil&gas industry has to follow strict regulations on managing maintenance and defects/failures. So they will run either an [ERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning) or [EAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_asset_management) system.

These systems will have a wealth of information - if you can get hold of it.

Better still, usually the oil&gas industry have to use [RCM](https://www.rcm-handbook.com/), where they must define specific failure modes and their consequences. If you can get hold of that data, you can see what consequences they thought of (the designers), and then the ERP/EAM data will tell you the failures that actually happened.